# Identify sales order from an invoice - suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there an easy way to identify a Sales order where the invoice was created from?

I have a suitescript is execute every time an invoice is created, I want to identify which sales order the invoice was originated from because I need a field's value inside the sales order which determine the next step in the invoice process.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the value of the field ID 'createdfrom'

Answer (score 0):

There is a salesInvoiced table that has Transaction =id of CustInv and uniquekey = transactionLine.uniquekey